# Why isn't Mathematica reducing my result to a number?

Tags: evaluation

I do not understad why the program do not show the number values. 
Even when I use N[xx].[image]

How can I simplify this?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: What does `FullForm[ClawMO]` return?

Comment: I just guessing, but from your sequence of evaluations I think what looks the operator + must be the string "+". Or -- much less likely -- somehow you have disassociated the operator + from the function `Plus`.

Comment: I would also guess that there is somewhere a string in the expression.

Comment: Hi Michael, the full form return is Times[28.1743067577245`,Power[Plus[2,Times[4.904258335022924`,TextCell[""]]],-1]]]

Comment: m_goldberg you have the reason with your first prediction.

Comment: It was a trouble with the operators because the sqrt function put spaces.
Thanks for all

Comment: You can also just end almost any statement with `//N` to get a numerical estimation.

Answer (score 4):

While this may or may not be closed, either as a "mistake" or as "not reproducible," let me just point out the general approach indicated by my comment.

When *Mathematica* is not behaving as expected, especially on such simple input as the OP's session-image shows, it is good to suspect that some invisible input might be causing the mischief.  This may be checked by examining the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) of the expression, in this case,

```
FullForm[ClawMO]
```

Indeed, the response by the OP shows that somehow some empty text is a hidden factor multiplying one of the numbers:

> ```
> Times[28.1743067577245`, Power[Plus[2, Times[4.904258335022924`, TextCell[""]]], -1]]
> ```

Therefore this product is non-numeric and cannot be combined with `2.`.

Comment: Ironically, you have the characters U+200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE U+200C ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER present in your answer from copying OP's comments. This rubbish is [inserted by SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91498/is-there-a-css-problem-on-stack-overflow/91512#91512) in an attempt to insert line breaks into comments, but it doesn't work for that purpose and results in contamination of comment code with invisible characters...

Comment: @OleksandrR. That's pretty funny.  Fixed (I think).